# Bug or wrong usage? Scrollbar broken for textual.Log when printing styled (coloured) lines

Tags: python, rich, python-textual

I'm trying to render colored text inside a `textual.Log` widget using `rich.Style`, but somehow the scrollbar gets scrambled when applying a `Style` to the individual lines.

Here is my code:

```py
from textual import work
from textual.app import App
from textual.widgets import Log
from rich.style import Style

class BrokenLog(App[None]):
    CSS = "Log { border: solid $accent; }"

    def compose(self):
        yield Log()

    async def on_mount(self):
        self.query_one(Log).write_lines(
            (Style(color="red") if i % 2 else Style(color="green")).render(f"line {i}")
            for i in range(100)
        )

BrokenLog().run()
```

And here is what the result looks like:

[image]

I suspect the width of the lines to be computed without the control sequences, but I don't know how to tell the `Log` widget to take them into account.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there another way to draw lines in a `Log` window with different color each?

I'm using `textual=0.46.0` and `rich=13.7.0` with Python `3.11.4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a Rule, Textual won't work with ansi escape sequences it didn't generate itself. You are also using `Log` which is designed for simple text, and doesn't support color.

You can use `RichLog` which does support anything Rich can render. The following will print alternating colors:

```py
from textual import work
from textual.app import App
from textual.widgets import RichLog
from rich.text import Text

class FixedLog(App[None]):
    CSS = "Log { border: solid $accent; }"

    def compose(self):
        yield RichLog()

    async def on_mount(self):
        log = self.query_one(RichLog)
        for i in range(100):
            log.write(Text(f"line {i}", style="red" if i%2 else "green"))

FixedLog().run()
```

Comment: I've expected something like that and turned of the color for now. I'm using `Log` rather than `RichLog` because it has the `write_lines()` method, which I expected to be more efficient when it comes to lots of lines/sec (but never actually compared it).